# Ubuntu not detecting usb on bootup, but detects after unplug and plug

Tags: usb

I have connected a usb to the ubuntu machine before booting. When I boot it does not detect the usb,I verified this in lsusb. But as soon as I unplug and plug the usb it starts detecting the usb. I want the system to be able to detect the usb after bootup without doing this unplug-plug. Is there any way I can achieve this through terminal commands.

any help is appreciated.
thanks